# Estimating $\bigg|\mathbb{P}\bigg(\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\theta_jX_j\leq x\bigg)-\mathbb{P}\bigg(\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n-1}\theta_jX_j\leq x\bigg)\bigg|$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

Suppose that $X_1, ... , X_n$ are independent, identically-distributed random variables and $\theta_1,...,\theta_n$ are some real coefficients. Then, for given $x\in\mathbb{R}$, how can we estimate the difference
$$\bigg|\mathbb{P}\bigg(\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\theta_jX_j\leq x\bigg)-\mathbb{P}\bigg(\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n-1}\theta_jX_j\leq x\bigg)\bigg|$$
(note that the second sum has $n-1$ terms). I think that if we take the last coefficient $\theta_n$ to be small, then the above difference should also be small. I, however, do not know how to estimate that difference in terms of $\theta_n$.

$\textbf{Update}:$ Although there are already 2 answers given below, I am wondering whether it is possible to derive a formula that explicitly estimates the above difference in terms of $\theta_n$ so that by taking $\theta_n$ to be small it can be clearly seen that the difference above is also small. If needed, additional conditions on random variables $X_i$ may be imposed (e.g., bounded moments of given order).

Comment: Do you have any more information about $X_i$ (such as the distribution or the range of its value) or $n$ (large or not)?

Comment: I would be glad to know under which additional assumptions on $X_i$ the considered difference is "small" (assuming that $\theta_n$ is small).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a reasonably clean bound if we assume that $X_i$ have a probability density function with respect to Lebesgue measure.

Suppose $\theta >0$ and $X,Y$ are random variables. Suppose that $X$ has a probability density function, and that this probability density function is bounded above by $L$. Then
\begin{align}|\mathbb{P}(X + \theta Y \leq x ) - \mathbb{P}( X \leq x)| &= |\mathbb{E}[ 
     \mathrm{1}\{ X + \theta Y \leq x \} - \mathrm{1} \{ X \leq x \} ]|\\
&\leq \mathbb{E} |\mathrm{1}\{ X + \theta Y \leq x \} - \mathrm{1} \{ X \leq x \}  | \\
&\leq \mathbb{P}( X \leq x, X+\theta Y > x) + \mathbb{P}(X+\theta Y \leq x, X > x)\\
&\leq \mathbb{P} ( x - \theta Y < X \leq x , Y > 0) + \mathbb{P}( x < X \leq x - \theta Y , Y < 0).
\end{align}
Note that $\mathbb{P} ( x - \theta Y < X \leq x , Y > 0) = \mathbb{E}[ \mathbb{P} ( x - \theta Y < X \leq x | Y ) \mathrm{1}_{Y > 0} ) \leq  \mathbb{E}[ \theta L Y \mathrm{1}_{Y > 0} )$. Likewise, $\mathbb{P}( x < X \leq x - \theta Y , Y < 0) \leq \mathbb{E}[ - \theta L Y \mathrm{1}_{Y < 0}]$. Thus
\begin{align}|\mathbb{P}(X + \theta Y \leq x ) - \mathbb{P}( X \leq x)| \leq \theta L \mathbb{E}[|Y|].
\end{align}

In particular, if $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \theta_i X_i$ has a density function upper bounded by $L_{n-1}$, then
\begin{align}|\mathbb{P}(\sum_{i=1}^n \theta_i X_i \leq x ) - \mathbb{P}( \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \theta_i X_i \leq x)| \leq \theta_n L_{n-1} \mathbb{E}[|X_n|].
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

Let us analyse this problem in the context of random variables that admit a density function. Let this density be $f,$ so $X_i$ is distributed according to $f$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n.$ We will also assume that $\theta_i \geq 0$ for the simplicity of the discussion - however the general case can be treated in a similar fashion. Note that $\mathbb{P}(\theta_i X_i \leq x) = \mathbb{P}(X_i \leq \frac{x}{\theta_i}),$ so the CDF of $Y_i := \theta_i X_i$ is $F_i(x) = F(\frac{x}{\theta_i})$ and its PDF is $f_i(x) = \frac{1}{\theta_i} f(\frac{x}{\theta_i}).$ In the following, let $W := \sum_{1 \leq j \leq n - 1} \theta_j X_j$ and $Z(\theta) := W + \theta X_n.$ The [classical result regarding the density of the sum of independent random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions) yields that
$$f_W(w) = f_1 \ast f_2 \ast \dots \ast f_{n - 1} (w), \text{ } f_{Z(\theta_n)}(z) = f_W \ast f_n (z).$$ It follows that
$$\mathbb{P}(Z(\theta_n) \leq x) = \int_{- \infty}^x f_Z(z) dz = \int_{- \infty}^x \int_{- \infty}^\infty f_W(w) f_n(z - w) d w d z = \\ \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_W(w) \mathbb{P}(\theta_n X_n \leq x - w) d w = \int_{- \infty}^\infty f_W(w) F(\frac{x - w}{\theta_n}) d w = \int_{- \infty}^\infty F_W(x - w) f_n(w) d w.$$
We also have that $$\mathbb{P}(W \leq x) = \mathbb{P}(Z(0) \leq x) = F_W(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty F_W(x) f_n(w) d w.$$
With the notation $F(\theta) := \mathbb{P}(Z(\theta) \leq x),$ we want to estimate $\vert F(\theta) - F(0) \vert.$ Note that $F(\theta)$ is differentiable with respect to $\theta$ and
$$F'(\theta) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{w - x}{\theta^2} f_W(w) f(\frac{x - w}{\theta}) d w = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{w}{\theta} f_W(w) f_{\theta X}(x - w) d w - \frac{x}{\theta} f_{Z(\theta)}(x).$$
A subsequent application of the Mean Value Theorem would then provide the estimate
$$\vert \mathbb{P}(W + \theta X_n \leq x) - \mathbb{P}(W \leq x)\vert = \vert \theta \vert \vert \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{w}{\theta_0} f_W(w) f_{\theta_0 X}(x - w) d w - \frac{x}{\theta_0} f_{Z(\theta_0)}(x) \vert.$$
Of course, one would hope to obtain an upper bound on the absolute value of the derivative, but none very obvious ones in this very general framework come to mind. If you have any additional information regarding the problem, I would be more than happy to circle back to my answer and edit it with additional information. Nonetheless, I hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a detailed and helpful answer. Are there any additional conditions that can be imposed on $X_i$ (e.g., bounded moments of certain order) to make sure that the expression $\vert \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{w}{\theta_0} f_W(w) f_{\frac{X}{\theta_0}}(x - w) d w - \frac{x}{\theta_0} f_{Z(\theta_0)}(x) \vert$ is also small (or bounded)?

Comment: Because as $\theta_0\in(0,\theta)$, then taking $\theta$ to be small will result in $1/\theta_0$ to be very big.

Comment: I fixed a few typos in my answer and added a comment regarding the implicit assumption that all the $\theta_i$ are positive which was made for simplicity's sake. Heuristically the $\theta_0$ in the denominator "sort of cancels out" in the end, but I can't figure out a formal proof yet, I will try to find one when I wake up. Here is the informal reason for my remark: integrating the derivative of $F$ with respect to $x$ yields $\mathbb{E}[X]$ no matter the choice of $\theta,$ hence the "cancelling out" I mentioned. Of course, a proper argument is needed and I shall think about that.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $X_1,X_2,...$ are continuous random variables.

Let $M(t)$ be the moment generating function of $X_1$.

Assume $\theta_1,\theta_2,...\in \text{domain}(M)$

If $S_n=\theta_1X_1+\dots +\theta_n X_n$ then from Markov $$\mathbb{P}(S_n\leq t)=\mathbb{P}(e^{-S_n}\geq e^{-t})\leq \frac{\mathbb{E}(e^{-S_n})}{e^{-t}}$$ This provides us with an upper bound for $F_{S_n}(t)$.

$F_{S_n}(t)\leq e^tM(-\theta_1)\times\dots \times M(-\theta_n)$

We can get a lower bound with a similar strategy. $$F_{S_n}(t)=1-\mathbb{P}(S_n>t)\geq 1-\frac{M(\theta_1)\times \dots \times M(\theta_n)}{e^t}$$

If $a_n(t),b_n(t)$ are these respective lower and upper bounds, then $F_{S_{n}}(t)-F_{S_{n-1}}(t)$ must belong to $$[-b_{n-1}(t),1-a_{n-1}(t)]$$ I'm not sure how "tight" these bounds are. Maybe someone else does? Note this interval doesn't depend on the value of $\theta_n$, which is nice.

If these bounds aren't meaningful you can make adjustments by enforcing a more suitable bound, which of course should depend on the features of population from which we're sampling to get our iid sequence $X_1,X_2,...$

Answer (score 2):

Rather than a concrete answer, this is more of sketch of a smoothness-based approach that may be useful (and is too long to put in the comments). The first part is quite similar to Actually Fritz's answer above.

---

Let's write $Z = \sum_{i \le n} \theta_i X_i.$ Let me write $P_X$ for the law of $X$, and $p_Z$ for the density of $Z$, assuming that this exists.

Then, using independence, note that $$ P(Z + \theta_nX_n \le x) = \int P(Z \le x - \theta_n u) \mathrm{P}_{X_n}(\mathrm{d}u).$$ Therefore, the difference you're interested in is $$ \int (P(Z \le x - \theta_nu) - P(Z \le x)) P_{X_n}(\mathrm{d}u).$$ If the CDF of $Z$ is smooth, say twice differentiable, and if $\theta_n$ is small, then by Taylor's theorem, we can approximate $$P(Z \le x - \theta_n u) - P(Z \le x) =- \theta_n u p_Z(x) + \theta_n^2 u^2 p_Z'(x + \xi(\theta_nu)\theta_n u),$$ where $\xi \in [0,1]$. This means that to the first order, the difference works out to $$ -\theta \mu_X p_Z(x) + O(\theta_n^2).$$ Strictly speaking, we would need some conditions for the above to hold: for instance, it suffices that $X$ has bounded support, and that $p'_Z$ does not behave too wildly. Note that if $\mu_X$ is $0$, then the action shifts to the second order term (and writing the result in a simple way would demand control on $p''_Z$. Of course, all of this depends strongly on the law of $X$ and $Z,$ and its hard to say something generic but powerful without this.

One setting where one can reduce the dependence on the precise behaviour of $Z,X$ is if the coefficients $\theta_i$ are evenly small, so that, e.g., the Lindeberg condition holds for $Z$. In the simplest case, suppose that $X_i$ are bounded, have unit variance, and $\theta_i = 1/\sqrt{n-1}$ for each $i \le n-1$. Then $Z - \sqrt{n-1}\mu$ is distributed roughly as a Gaussian. If $x = \sqrt{n-1}\mu + O(1)$ (which is the interesting region, since for $x$ much smaller or larger, the LLN would remove so much mass around $x$ that the whole approach is somewhat moot), then (using Berry-Esseen type results), we would conclude that the difference scales as $$ -\theta_n \mu_X \phi(x - \sqrt{n}\mu) + O(\theta_n^2) \pm O(1/\sqrt{n}).$$ The catch here is that the $O(1/\sqrt{n})$ term may be quite large compared to $\theta_n$, washing out some of the power of the result. In general with Lindeberg-based Berry-Esseen theorems, you should be able to generalise this to varying $\theta$s (as long as none is too large), and use that to say something concrete, although again only up to an additive factor of $1/\sqrt{n},$ meaning that if $\theta_n \lesssim 1/\sqrt{n},$ the result may not be useful in capturing the dependence on $\theta_n$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $S=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \theta_i X_i$ and $$g(\theta) = \mathbb P\left(S+\theta X_n \le x\right).$$

You can see that a good approximation of $g(\theta) - g(0)$ can be obtained by using Tylor series and to do that you need to be able to compute the derivatives of $g$ at $0$. For example the first derivative is:

$$g'(\theta) = -\mathbb E\left[X_n f_S(x-\theta X_n)\right]$$ So $g'(0) = -f_S(x) \mathbb E[X]$. You can also proves by induction that:

$$g^{(k)}(0) = (-1)^k f^{(k-1)}_S(x) \mathbb E [X^k]$$